# is_copy_assignable() returns false when copy assignment defined

Tags: c++, g++4.8

Why does `is_copy_assignable()` return false here (g++ 4.8.2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class thing {
    public:
        int n;
        thing () : n(1) { }
        thing (thing& x) : n(x.n) { }
        thing& operator= (thing& x) {
            n = x.n;
            return *this;
        }
};

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    cout << is_copy_assignable<thing>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that should be `const thing& x` in the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the expected signature for the copy assignment operator is :

```
 thing& operator= (const thing& x)  // note the const parameter
```

This returns `true`.

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/kTbhhO).

Looking at the requirements for [CopyAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) (required by `is_copy_assignable`), a `const T` must be assignable.

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_copy_assignable<T>` is formally defined in §20.9.4.3 [meta.unary.prop] as `std::is_assignable<T &, const T &>`.

Now this (`std::is_assignable<T, U>`) in turn requires `declval<T>() = declval<U>();` to be well-formed. For your class, it is not, since your copy-assignment operator only takes a non-const `T &`, so it cannot be assigned a `const T`.

For another way of looking at it, see cppreference's [`CopyAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) page.